# How to run onSubmit={} only after the props have updated?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, redux, firebase-authentication

I want to run onSubmit on my form only after my props that I receive from the reducer update.

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    authError: state.auth.authError  // I want this to update before the action.
  };
};
```

If I console.log authError in onSutmit handler I receive the old authError. The second time I run it, I receive the updated authError.

```
  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("error exists?", this.props.authError);
    this.props.signIn(this.state); //dispatches a login action
    this.handleHideLogin(); // hides the form after action is dispatched
};
```

I want to hide the form only after the action is dispatched and the error is null. (it returns null automatically if the authentication succeeds)

I tried using setTimeout() and it technically works, but I want to know if there is a more "proper" way to do it.

```
handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.signIn(this.state);

     setTimeout(() => {
       if (this.props.authError) {
         console.log("returns error =>", this.props.authError);
       } else {
         console.log("no error =>", this.props.authError);
         this.handleHideLogin();
       }
     }, 500);
  };
```

part of my component for reference

```
<form onSubmit={!this.props.authError ? this.handleSubmit : null}> 
   //the above onSubmit is different if I use the setTimeout method.
          <div className="modal-login-body">
            <div className="modal-login-input">
              <input
                type="email/text"
                name="email"
                autoComplete="off"
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                required
              />
              <label htmlFor="email" className="label-name">
                <span className="content-name">EMAIL</span>
              </label>
            </div>
            <div className="modal-login-input">
              <input
                type="password"
                name="password"
                autoComplete="off"
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                required
              />
              <label htmlFor="password" className="label-name">
                <span className="content-name">PASSWORD</span>
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="my-modal-footer">
            <p className="login-failed-msg">
              {this.props.authError ? this.props.authError : null}
            </p>
            <button type="submit" className="complete-login-button">
              LOGIN
            </button>
            <a href="CHANGE" className="forgot-password">
              <u>Forgot your password?</u>
            </a>
          </div>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that `this.props.signIn` is an async function.
And thus `this.props.authError` is updated asynchronously and that's why if you setup the timeout it works in some cases (when you get the response shorter than 5 seconds).

One way to solve it is using `then` and `catch` without updating the state of the form

```
handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.signIn(this.state).then(resp => {
        this.setState({userIsValid: true, failure: null})
        this.onUpdate(userIsValid);
    })
    .catch(err => {
       this.setState({userIsValid: false, failure: "Failed to login"})
    });
}
```

and use `if-else` to determine whether to show the form or to display your website

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    if (this.state.isValidUser) {
      return <Main />
    } else {
      return <LoginForm onUpdate={(isValid) => {this.setState({isValidUser: isValid})} />
    }
  }
}
```

In other words, the LoginForm component stores username, password, failure (error message why login failed) and isValidUser (to determine if login is successful).
The App has a state to determine what to show, the website or the login component. Using `onUpdate` that is passed as props to the login component we can update the state of App and show the website if login is successful.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I didn't really want to alter my state because I would have to change all my Auth setup. I appreciate the affort.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by conditonal rendering on the entire component.
I used Redirect from react-router-dom to just not render the element if I'm logged in.

If I'm logged in I don't need to display the login form anyway.

```
   if (this.props.loggedOut) {
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        //...
      </form>
    } else {
      return <Redirect to="/" />;
    }
```